# SSISDB Transaction Log Backup

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-agent, etl

I have several SSIS packages jobs running, and some months ago my disk got full because the size of the SSISDB database.

I noticed that the cleanup_server_retention_window was set to 365 days, and I changed it to one day. (It is a development server, and at this point I really dont care about the history).

The (big) problem, obviously, is now that the transaction log grows a lot and fast.

To prevent this, I start performing a full backup every week and a transaction log backup every day, and the size of the database is now controlled.

However, some more experienced guys are telling me that this is not the best aproach to this issue, but I cant see any problem with it..

I would like to know if there is a better solution for this.

Comment: Its funny that the person who is telling you this is not the best approach hasn't told you what the best approach is...  Can you set the recovery model to Simple?  Then the tlog won't grow.  Note that you won't be able to recover this db to a point in time, but I'm not sure if that's necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the recovery model to SIMPLE and be done with it since this is a Development server and you mentioned you don't care about the history.

For more information on recovery models and transaction logs, see [this excellent post](http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2008/07/23/recovery-model-and-transaction-logs/) from Gail Shaw.